# React 'Hello World' Is not Loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am extremely new to React as this is my First Lesson. Following is my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World with React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id= "react-container"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
const title = React.createElement(
    'h1'
    {id: 'title', className: 'header'},
    'Hello World'
    )

ReactDOM.render(
    title,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
    )
```

However, nothing is rendered in the browser.
Both the script and the Html page is in the same folder. There must be a very simple mistake, so please anyone help me on this? Thanks for your time!

Comment: no comma `,` after `h1`

Comment: For all you guys answering a question like this (4 answers so far): don't do it. There is a close reason for that: *"This question was caused by a simple typographical error."*. Just write a comment, like the [user above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103484/react-hello-world-is-not-loaded#comment85212151_49103484), and vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing a comma in `createElement`. The syntax being

```
React.createElement(component, props, ...children)
```

```js
const title = React.createElement(
  'h1', {
    id: 'title',
    className: 'header'
  },
  'Hello World'
)

ReactDOM.render(
  title,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="react-container"></div>
```

Good luck with React!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `,` after your `'h1'`

```js
const title = React.createElement(
  'h1', {
    id: 'title',
    className: 'header'
  },
  'Hello World'
)


ReactDOM.render(
  title,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
)
/**/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="react-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
    <!--
      Note: this page is a great way to try React but it's not suitable for production.
      It slowly compiles JSX with Babel in the browser and uses a large development build of React.

      To set up a production-ready React build environment, follow these instructions:
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-an-existing-app.html

      You can also use React without JSX, in which case you can remove Babel:
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is not `,` after the `hi` string. put it

```
const title = React.createElement(
    'h1',
    {id: 'title', className: 'header'},
    'Hello World'
    )
```